# Protractor: How to wait for AJAX to be loaded

Tags: typescript, protractor

How to wait for AJAX in Protractor. Question is, to wait for AJAX to be loaded.

Comment: please provide more details and a minimum sample so we can recreate your issue.

Comment: I was trying to work out how to wait for AJAX calls to complete in Protractor.

Comment: Protractor, for angular apps, handles this for you. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan please provide more details